# Not include objects used in a function in parameter

Tags: r

I have a huge dataframe, `tab1`.

In a function, I use `tab1`to create a second dataframe, `tab2`.

Is it correct to not put `tab1` in the parameters of the function and just call the dataframe when needed?

I understand that when a function is called, a new environment is created. So is doing that spare me the copy of `tab1` when calling the function?

I have the intuition that it is not good practice, as it make the function not reusable. But in the same time, if it could increase the speed of my code, why would it be not correct?

edit: I found my answer here, slide 20-21:
 http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~statcur/Workshop2/Presentations/functions.pdf
after looking at the exemple of @Roland.

I quote: "[in case of function inside a function]
In this case the environment in which a function is defined is the body of another function"

What could go wrong:

```
### ok
tab1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = "exemple")
x <- 2

func1 <- function (g) { tab1[g, 1]^x}

func1(c(1, 3))
[1] 1 9

### not ok:

tab1 <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = "exemple")
x <- 4

func2 <- function (d) {
  x <- 3 
y <- function (d) { 
  tab1[d, 1]^x
}
y(d)
}

func2(c(1, 3))
[1]  1 27
```

Comment: Can you give example code?

Comment: where is your code and example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pass everything as a function parameter to avoid scoping problems.

There is no copy for a bound variable:

```
DF <- data.frame(a = 1:5)
fun1 <- function() address(DF)
fun1()
#[1] "000000002148C950"

fun2 <- function(df) {force(df); address(df)}
fun2(DF)
#[1] "000000002148C950"
```

Comment: Thanks, your exemple is great. But I have difficulties to understand the `force` function. I tried without, and it works as well.

Comment: `force` forces evaluation of the promise. It's probably not relevant here, but I wanted to make it super-obvious.